# Is it possible to enable or disable a tab in Ionic3?

Tags: html, ionic3

Is it possible to enable and disable a tab in Ionic3 application?

I try to use *ngIf to do that in html, but each time when setting is changed from false to true, an new tab is added; when setting is changed from true to false, the tab doesn't disappear.

html is:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab0Root" [tabTitle]="tab0Title" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [tabTitle]="tab1Title" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab *ngIf="setting==true" [root]="tab2Root" [tabTitle]="tab2Title" tabIcon="setting"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Thanks.

Comment: add [disabled]="isDisabled " where  isDisabled  is variable in your .ts file

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating [Ali Mhanna's comment answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792230/is-it-possible-to-enable-or-disable-a-tab-in-ionic3#comment111043700_62792230):

The `*ngIf="condition"` you're using will actually not show the html tag element if the condition is false.

If you want to disable the tag html element instead, you could use `[diabled]="condition"`

So, using your own code's example:

---

#### page.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab0Root" [tabTitle]="tab0Title" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [tabTitle]="tab1Title" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab *ngIf="isShowTab" [disabled]="!isTabEnabled" [root]="tab2Root" [tabTitle]="tab2Title" tabIcon="setting"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

---

#### page.ts

```
private isShowTab: boolean = false; // will NOT SHOW tab if false
private isTabEnabled: boolean = false; // will DISABLE tab if false
```

---

Notice the use of `!` before `isTabEnabled` on `[disabled]` (.html), denying the boolean, meaning it will only disable when `isTabEnabled` is **false**.